# problems with hook_form_alter()

Tags: forms

```
function heihachi_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id) {
    if ($form_id == 'ipaper_node_form') {
           unset($form['body']);
        }
}
```

the code above removed body field in node/add/ipaper. But how can i remove body inside a node? (mysite.com/node/4420 for example).

And 2nd question is: i did `print_r($form)` inside mymodule.module and now im watching in the page source code and see this:

```
Array
{

    [#node] => stdClass Object
        (
            [uid] => 1
            [name] => heihachi
```

i am on the right way if i use this construction to print the name for example:
$form['#node'] => ['name'] ?? Guess not.. :) That stdClass Object is confusing me :(

Answer (score 3):

A better approach is to edit the content type settings and omit body altogether.

In Drupal 6, you can do this by going to `/admin/content/types/ipaper` and leave the "Body field label" empty.

In Drupal 7, go to `/#overlay=admin/structure/types/manage/ipaper/fields` and delete the Body field.

If you really need to keep old content in the node body, then use `hook_nodeapi()` with `$op == 'view` to unset `$node->body`

Answer (score 1):

The if $form['body'] is where the output is being sourced from, unset should work fine, but as this is form_alter I'm not entirely sure whether the node will already have been rendered by the time it's called.

You'll be able to get to the node name using:

```
$form['#node']->name
```

rather than:

```
$form['#node']['name']
```

which would be what you'd use if it was an array rather than an object

Comment: Thanks... now just 1 question left: how to unsed body inside node :)

Comment: Is the problem with unsetting the body in the node that this unset code is only getting called for the form 'ipaper_node_form'? Whereas you want to remove the body from other nodes?

Comment: inside from node view. From node/add/ipaper i've successfully removed it

Answer (score 1):

You should implement [hook_nodeapi](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--hooks--core.php/function/hook_nodeapi/6):

```
function heihachi_nodeapi(&$node, $op, $a3 = NULL, $a4 = NULL) {
  if ($op == 'prepare') {
    unset($node->body);
  }
```

Comment: Thanks, but its impossible with just hook_form_alter?

Comment: as far as I am aware, it's impossible.

Comment: oops, when im viewing node/4480 - node->body is still there, whats wrong? I shouldn't use 'prepare'?